# Publishing WPF application

Tags: wpf, .net-core, publish

When I publish my application it works fine on my computer however, when I try to run it on another computer it keeps asking me to download the specific .net core runtimes. My target framework is 3.1 and it keeps asking for the 3.1.4 runtimes or to install the 3.1.0 runtimes. I downloaded a newer version of the .net core sdk that goes along with the runtimes (3.1.300) but still no change. I tried changing my .netcore framework to 3.1.3 aswell but it still just shows 3.1, probably because 3.1.3 is a part of 3.1. Not sure how to address this issue other than to install 3.1.0 on the other users computers aswell.

Below is my csproj:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>VRI_configurator</RootNamespace>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ApplicationIcon>KHVT.png</ApplicationIcon>
    <PackageIcon>KHVT.png</PackageIcon>
    <PackageIconUrl />
    <StartupObject>VRI_configurator.App</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Resources\img\KHVT.png" />
    <None Include="/Resources/img/KHVT.png">
      <Pack>True</Pack>
      <PackagePath></PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\img\KHVT.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\img\search_icon.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\img\username_icon.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\img\password_icon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MahApps.Metro" Version="2.0.0-alpha0748" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf" Version="1.1.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.20" />
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Core" Version="7.2.0.1422" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your csproj? It might be an issue with how your csproj is defined.

Comment: In the publish profile, you can switch the deployment mode to 'Self-contained'. That setting will bundle all the necessary runtime files with the application.

Comment: You can get this sort of issue if you compile for 32bit and installed the 64 bit version of the framework or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching I found the solution to my problem, I added the xml below to my csproj file under the PropertyGroup. Now it expects 3.1.4 or lower runtime framework to be installed on the users computer and no longer searches for 3.1.0.

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>3.1.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your end users to be required to install the .NET Core runtime to be able to run your app, you could publish it as a *self-contained* app.

Click on "Edit" or "New" under the profile in the Publish wizard in Visual Studio and change or set the deployment mode to `Self-contained` and the target runtime to either `win-x86` or `win-x64`.

This will produce an application that includes the .NET Core runtime and libraries, and your application and its dependencies. Users of the application can then run it on a machine that doesn't have the .NET Core runtime installed.

Please refer to the docs for more information:

[.NET Core application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

[Deploy .NET Core apps with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156)

Comment: I have tried that, but it left me with one huge file which was not really an option in my case sadly.